# Django displays tow different timezones for the same model attribute when viewing in admin site vs a query for the model in a script

Tags: django, django-timezone

How to make consistant timezone across Django.
In my `settings.py` I have `TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'` and `USE_TZ = True`. I have a model

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

if I view a field from that model (say pk=1) it correctly displays value for an `eastern` timezone. From my terminal, when I run `python manage.py shell` and make a query for that same field (pk=1), it will print the date_time attribute of that field in UTC format as follows: `datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 22, 0, 19, 28, 696739, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

Why is this happening? And how can I make it so that all queries use the correct timezone when filtering by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django template level automatically converts the UTC to your local time. But during in model level, they are treated in UTC.

You can use the builtin [timezone utils](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) `localtime` to convert to your desired output.